# VHDL error, even though I generate a bit file

Tags: error-handling, vhdl

I have made this program in VHDL, alle syntax's are fine, and I have tried to double check all the port maps, but I get some warnings that causes the program not to work, even tough it can generate the bit file.. anybody here who can help please??

```
    library IEEE;
    use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;


    entity topMain is
    port(   clk   : in std_logic; 
          alarm : in std_logic_vector (1 downto 0);
        d_open : in std_logic_vector (1 downto 0);      
        d_closed  : in std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);        
        d_out : out std_logic_vector (1 downto 0));         
    end topMain;

    architecture Behavioral of topMain is

    type state_type is (S0,S1,S3);


    signal NS, Current_State : state_type;
    begin

    process (clk, alarm)
    begin

    if alarm ="11" then 
        Current_State <= S3;  -- 
    
    elsif rising_edge (clk) then 
        Current_State <= NS;   -- state change
    end if;
    end process;

    --------------------------------


    process(Current_State,d_open, d_closed, clk)
    begin
        case Current_State is
  
    ----
    when S3 =>      d_out <= "11";
            if (d_open = "10") then
                        NS <= S3;

                    elsif (d_closed = "01") then
                    NS <= S3;
                    elsif (d_closed = "00") then 
                    NS <= S3;

            end if;
        
----
              
      when S0 =>         d_out <= "10"; -- open door
                     if ( d_open = "10" ) then
                      NS <= S0;
                             
                             elsif (d_closed= "01") then
                             NS <= S1;
                             elsif (d_closed = "10") then
                             NS <= S0;
                        
                else   
                    NS <= S0;
                end if;

                     
    when S1 =>        d_out <= "01";  -- open door
                if ( d_closed = "01" ) then
                    NS <= S1;
                    elsif (d_open <= "10") then
                    NS <= S0;
                    elsif (d_open <= "01") then
                    NS <= S1;
                else   
                    NS <= S1;
                end if;
            
        end case;
   
   end process;
    end Behavioral;
```

And in case anybody can take a look at it, this is the full project.
Its a simple program containg a finite state machine with 3 changes, simulating a burglar alarm.
When alarm is off, you can open door and close it, but if its on, you cant do anything. at lease thats what i was trying to make, altough i am newbie. Please forgive me for any inconvenience it may cause you.

http://www.abmy.dk/BAlarm.zip

The warnings I am getting right now:

WARNING:Xst:819 - "C:/Xilinx/OP/BAlarm/topMain.vhd" line 36: One or more signals are missing in the process sensitivity list. To enable synthesis of FPGA/CPLD hardware, XST will assume that all necessary signals are present in the sensitivity list. Please note that the result of the synthesis may differ from the initial design specification. The missing signals are:

WARNING:Xst:737 - Found 3-bit latch for signal . Latches may be generated from incomplete case or if statements. We do not recommend the use of latches in FPGA/CPLD designs, as they may lead to timing problems.
WARNING:Xst:647 - Input  is never used. This port will be preserved and left unconnected if it belongs to a top-level block or it belongs to a sub-block and the hierarchy of this sub-block is preserved.
WARNING:PhysDesignRules:372 - Gated clock. Clock net top/NS_not0001 is sourced
by a combinatorial pin. This is not good design practice. Use the CE pin to
control the loading of data into the flip-flop.
WARNING:Route:455 - CLK Net:top/NS_not0001 may have excessive skew because

Comment: What exactly are the warnings you are getting? What exactly do you mean when you say it "doesn't work"? Have you tried running a simulation? You must help us if you want us to help you.

Comment: I have added all the warninngs i am getting so far in the question..

Answer (score 2):

The `NS` signal is not assigned in all branches of the combinatorial process
`process(Current_State, d_open, d_closed, clk)`, which will infer latches; see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/20394822/2352082 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/20411227/2352082

The code:

```
when S3 => d_out <= "11";
           if (d_open = "10") then
             ns <= S3;
           elsif (d_closed = "01") then
             ns <= S3;
           elsif (d_closed = "00") then
             ns <= S3;
           end if;
```

does not have an `else`, so if neither of the previous conditions
are TRUE, then `NS` is not assigned, which results in a latch inferred by
synthesis.

You may fix this by adding an `else` with proper assign `NS` value assign, like:

```
           ...
           else
             ns <= S0;  -- TBD[S0 is only example; use correct value]
           end if;
```

I don't see any signals missing in the process sensitivity list, but `clk` is
included and not required in the last one, since this process implements combinatorial design.

Comment: Hej Morten,
Kan se du også er fra DK, helt sikkert :) .. Hvor præcis tilføjer jeg when others til koden?

Comment: @abmy: Yes, I am also from Denmark, but lets keep the conversion in English for the sake of others ;-)  I have corrected my previous answer, since it was not correct.  It is not the lack of an `when others =>` that causes the latch, bu the lack of an `else` in `if` of `when S3 =>`.  Please see the updated answer above.

Comment: I'll give it a try when I get home. Thanks.